# How make static view on any viewcontroller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I Have interesting question.
I have two screens, I need that would be the third screen elements (buttons, label) are static and do not change when you move from one screen to another. .
So MAIN DISPLAY 1 will be change, DISPLAY 2 too , but button and others(label for example) need be static.

Big Thanks for all help, sorry i don't have any code with this problem. Because i don't know how this make...

Comment: I can't see the problem here, and sorry for disappointing you, this question (which is not a question) is not that interesting, you have xib/storiboard files in which you can add your `static` views.

Comment: I know but how this make? If you do not want to show the code then tell me in which direction I should look for an answer/ Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you have a UI that won't change it's content you have to consider the following:

If the user can navigate from one screen to another, then you will have to create multiple view controllers(it can be done in other ways but this is the easiest and best way to doit) that will have their own UI, that can be easily created in storyboards like this:

Create a new project that use storyboars (you can use the Xcode templates that support your needs)

In your generated storyboard, drag and drop a new UINavigationController, and in the `Attributes inspector` check the `Is initial view controller`
         [image]

Drag another UIViewController into your storyboard, select your navigation controller, hold right click and drag to the newly added view controller, a popup will appear and from that popup select `root view controller`. Now the newly added view controller will be the first view that the app will display. On this view controller add your UI elements (buttons, labels, etc). If you want another screen to be shown when a user taps on a button, drag another view controller and select the button from which you want to display the next screen, hold right click drag to the newly added view controller, from the popup select `push`. Now when the user tap on the button the next view controller will be shown and as a bonus because you use iOS, the system will create a back button so that you can go back to your first view controller.

Ok, this is the a basic tutorial from which you can start and expand, but for that you will have to read more, spend nights on google/SO to find solutions, you will learn apple docs by heart and other things that are required so that you can be a great iOS developer.

My the iOS force be with you and Steve Jobs watch your steps.

Comment: O it's great idea, thanks, so i used: navigation controller - tab bar controller - and any view controllers. But for example i want have one view with tab bar controller but with out navigation bar, how it's make? I want up vote for you but i have only 10 reputation, sorry.

Comment: Accepted! You know how make for example some UiView make show on any views when app will start, with out navigation controller.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want :(

Comment: I want that UiView with some buttons UISlider and others show atop all any views but with out navigation controller. Because I use the tab bar with navigation controller, and I need everyone to be a top bars, and one view without

Comment: If you want to add some views on top of every view that will be presented when the user taps on one tab bar item, you have to create a subclass of UITabBarController and add those views as subviews of `YourSubclassOfUITabBarController.view`

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head:
you could put a view into your uiwindow and place your static elements there, and then give a transparent background to display1 and display2. then you can have the two displays forward their touches to the background elements to have actions on the buttons. im sorry i dont have any code, but i never tried that ;)

Answer (score 0):

A much better way is to instantiate your ViewController like so:

```
this.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController (StaticViewController.staticViewController, true);
```

Then inside your instantiated View Controller you setup a static variable that holds that instance of the View Controller:

```
public static StaticViewController staticViewController;
```

When the Static View Controller fires up for the first time:

```
staticViewController = this;
```

Now in the future when you fire up the Static View Controller (from wherever in your app) you can check to see if the StaticViewController.staticViewController variable is null or not.

Use simple if else logic to load it up accordingly:

```
if (StaticViewController.staticViewController == null) {
                StaticViewController.staticViewController staticViewController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("StaticViewController") as StaticViewController;
                this.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController (StaticViewController.staticViewController, true);
            } else {
                if(!StaticViewController.staticViewController.IsBeingPresented) //safeguard against click happy users
                    this.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController (StaticViewController.staticViewController, true);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add the static views to your `UINavigationController` or whatever controller you are using for managing multiple controllers.