# How to make a viewcontroller is not released when pop from navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have an `UINavigationController`, and then I push an `UIViewController` into this `navigationController`. 
 
Then I pop `viewController` from `navigationController`. In theory, this `viewController` will be released. But how can I retain this `viewController` . Because I need to push it again and keep `viewController's` state.
 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to refresh/reload/push the same VC with out delete the old data or  delete the old data

Comment: yes. It is kind of make the VC to static

Comment: see this link it helps u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596623/how-make-static-view-on-any-viewcontroller-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass `UINavigationController` and add a property `var myViewController: UIViewController?` in which you will save your view controller :

```
self.navigationController.myViewController = self
```